# Tests for my "LineGraph-from-AdjacencyMatrix" function

Tags: functions, graph-theory

I think I found a way to generate adjacency matrices $L$ of line graphs from the adjacence matrices $A$ of graphs. Now I want to test my function $L=f(A)$.

When $A$ is the cube, $L=f(A)$ already has the following correct properties:

- $L$ is $4$-regular, since the cube is cubic (haha), i.e. $3$-regular every edge has $4$ neighbouring edges
- $L$ has $24$ vertices, since $A$ has $24$ edges

What else? I don't want to draw the line graph from the adjacency matrix $L$.
If there are other graphs that a better to test my code, please go ahead..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try reading your matrix into Magma (or the online calculator), and interpret it as a graph.  From here you can test isomorphism against the built-in line graph operation (Magma has a nice IsIsomorphic(G1, G2) function for graphs).

Comment: Thanks would be nice if you could give an explicite example...